# Change EditText to Spinner with hardcoded data

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

In the following code, users can type the category desired and save to parse table. I want to avoid user input typos and would like to use a Spinner with hardcoded categories which the user can select from a dropdown menu. However I am unable to create a spinner as I have no previous experience with Spinner widgets. Can anyone provide a sample of how to accomplish this? This is my current code.

```
event.put("category", mEditCategory.getEditText().getText().toString()); // mEditCategory.getSpinner?????
            String strCat = mEditCategory.getEditText().getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strCat))
            {
                mEditCategory.setError("Especifique una categoria: trafico/chismes");
                return;
            }
```

Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at [this example and explanation by mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/). It is very thorough and you should be able to follow along easily. To answer your primary question about hardcoding the options: As you'll see in the example, you'll use a list specified in your strings.xml file which your code will load up.